# Improving in function clarity and efficiency in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new in programming so I need help in "cleaning up my code" if the code is a mess if not then please recommend some better commands that accomplish the same purpose of any line or multiple lines.
Here is my program.

```
import random


def random_num():
    lower_bound = input("what is your lower bound: ")
    upper_bound = input("What is your upper bound: ")
    trials = input("How many time would you like to try: ")
    random_number = random.randint(int(lower_bound), 
    int(upper_bound))
    user_input = input(
    "What is the number that I am thinking in the range "
    + lower_bound + "-" + upper_bound + " (only " + trials + " tries): ")
    ending = "Thanks For Playing"
    continue_game = "That's it. Do you want to continue the game? 
    (Yes/No): "
    count = 0
    while True:
       answer = int(user_input)
       if count == int(trials) - 1:
         lost = input("Sorry you have lost " + continue_game).lower()
            if lost in ["yes"]:
               random_num()
            else:
               return ending
       else:
           if answer == random_number:
               win = input(continue_game).lower()
               if win in ["yes"]:
                  random_num()
               else:
                  return ending
           elif answer >= random_number:
               user_input = input("The number is smaller than that: ")
           else:
               user_input = input("The number is bigger than that: ")
    count += 1
```

print(random_num())

Comment: As with any other prose you're recommended to structure your deliveries into an introduction, a main part and a finale. So try to structure your program the same way. The introduction shows the user a message and requests input, the main part does some processing on it and the final part displays some information about success/failure and shows the results. And now think in procedures.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/